# Find unique limit for an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to find the unique $z$ for which the following equation is true: If $x>-1$ and $y<1$ then:

$\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{1+t^{2}}+\int_{0}^{y}\frac{dt}{1+t^{2}} = \int_{0}^{z}\frac{dt}{1+t^{2}}$

I think it has something to do with the angle sum of tangent, but I do not see how.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what the indefinite integral $$\int \ \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^2}$$ is?

Comment: Yes is $tan^{-1}(t)$, but I do not know what to do to find $z$

Comment: So on the left you have a sum of arctangents, maybe there is a formula for that?

Comment: Got it!!! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we have that

$$
\arctan x + \arctan y = \arctan z,
$$
we can use the addition formula for $\arctan$, 
$$
\arctan x + \arctan y = \arctan\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right), \qquad xy < 1.
$$
If that condition is satisfied, then $z = \frac{x+y}{1-xy}$ would work. However, if that condition is not satisfied we would get a different answer, so maybe there is no unique $z$ given those restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of taste, I object to using the addition formula for the arctangent function to solve this problem because the question is essentially asking you to derive said addition formula. The formula can in fact be derived purely through basic properties of integrals with no reference to trigonometry.

Rescale both integrals on the LHS so that the interval of integral is $0\le u \le 1$ for both.

$$\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^2}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{1+x^2u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u;~~[t=xu],$$

and

$$\int_{0}^{y}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^2}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{y}{1+y^2u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u;~~[t=yu].$$

Now that the limits of integration are the same, we are free to combine the sum of the above two integrals into a single one:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^2}+\int_{0}^{y}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^2}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{1+x^2u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{y}{1+y^2u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{x}{1+x^2u^2}+\frac{y}{1+y^2u^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x(1+y^2u^2)+y(1+x^2u^2)}{(1+x^2u^2)(1+y^2u^2)}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(x+y)(1+xyu^2)}{(1+x^2u^2)(1+y^2u^2)}\,\mathrm{d}u.\\
\end{align}$$

Finally, transform the RHS back to the $t$ domain to extract the upper limit $z$.

Comment: This is a better answer than mine, but what is the final transformation you propose?